# Need help in validating domains

Tags: php, regex, dns

I need help in validating domains.
This is reg-ex I am using to validate: `/^[a-z\d][a-z\d-]{0,62}$/i`

It satisfies my needs but it fails to validate the domain 
like www.google*.com or  www.google*.com*. I don't want to save these type of domain.

This is the function I am using:

```
$pieces = explode(".",$domain_name);
foreach($pieces as $piece) {
    if (!preg_match('/^[a-z\d][a-z\d-]{0,62}$/i', $piece) || preg_match('/-$/', $piece)) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Any pointer on this?

Comment: It sounds like your question is "My regular expression doesn't allow asterisk characters in domain names, and I don't want it to, how can I fix this?" — which makes no sense.

Comment: Do you mean a wildcard with those asterisks?

Comment: yes I want to avoid only domain like this www.google*.com or www.google.com*

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to validate that a URL is properly formatted, use:

```
filter_var('http://example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
```

Regular expressions are expensive and should be avoided when there are viable alternatives.

Comment: For those using PHP < 5.3.3 - `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` would return `false` when there are dashes in a url. I think it was fixed in 5.3.3

Comment: @inhan - If you're on PHP < 5.3.3 you need to upgrade urgently.

Comment: @SDC No, I'm not. I just remember reading about this so I wanted others to make sure.